# Database Design for students marks per paper

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Earlier I've asked a question about an [attendance system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42840704/attendance-system-using-php-mysql/45544270). In the same system, I'm also having a separate table to store students marks. Now, before my question I would like to show what I've done so far:

In every semester there are 2 papers. There are 6 semesters to complete the course. In first paper a student can have a maximum marks of 75 and the second paper a marks of 25. Now, I've build a simple table `students_marks` as follows:

```
Name        | Type 
------------|-------
marks_id    | int
s_id        | int
sem_id      | int
sessionYear | varchar(11)
paper_one   | decimal(11,0)
paper_two   | decimal(11,0)
```

Now, `marks_id` is a `primary key`, while `s_id` and `sem_id` are `foreign keys` to two other tables `student_info` and `semester`.

To output the marks obtained I would do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `student_marks` 
JOIN `student_info` ON student_marks.s_id = student_info.s_id 
WHERE student_info.deleted = ? 
AND `sem_id` = ? AND `sessionYear` = ?
ORDER BY `class_roll`
```

What I didn't realize was that on the 5th and 6th Semester there are 4 papers with each paper maximum marks of 50. Now if I add two more column to the above table it would be redundant to the other semesters where I wont need to have 4 papers.

I'm looking for help to re-design this table so as to enable me to incorporate the new papers.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm using MySQL database and PHP for creating this application.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: `paper` should probably be its own table holding the paper *id*, *name*, *maximum mark* and so on; you'd then have a `mark` table (holding the mark oddly enough) with a `PRIMARY` (or `UNIQUE`) compound key comprised of *semester id*, *student id* and *paper id*

Comment: @CD001 can you please explain more. I've gone through many tutorials, and other questions in this forum, I couldn't get a clear answer, but many tutorial point to your direction but they just confuses me.

Comment: I don't think it's opinion based. Your schema design is flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry Their: *"My question is should I have a separate tables for the 5th and 6th Semester and query accordingly or is there a better way to design this table to make it more efficient and that if there is any future addition of papers I could just incorporate easily?"* - suggests it (opinion-based).

Comment: @fdiengdoh - it's called [Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (3NF) - *the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key so help me Codd* - it's a bit broad to answer on SO but there's plenty of information available ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I may have ask it wrongly. I actually want a better solution not an opinion base. Should I change the question?

Comment: Also DECIMAL (11,0) is an odd data type

Comment: @fdiengdoh Yes, I suggest you rephrase it please.

Comment: I've just updated the question. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a more normalised form:

```
create table student (id int, -- pk this one
                      studentinfo ... )-- all the student info

create table attendance (studentid int, -- fk to student
                         semesterid int)


create table paper (studentid INT, --fk to student table
                    selemsterid int, -- fk to attendance table
                    paperid INT, -- one for each paper
                    paperdate date, -- allows retakes
                    papermark decimal(11,0) ) -- Store the marks

select s.*, p.*
from student s
inner join attendance a
on a.studentid = s.id
inner join paper p
on p.studentid = s.id
and p.semesterid = s.semesterid
```

Comment: Thanks, would look into this and will get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

In your `students_marks` table you have columns `sem_id` and `sessionYear`. I assume that you can find out the year from `sem_id`, so the `sessionYear` column is unnecessary. Remove it.

Now you can have **just one column `paper_grade`** and enter every paper on a separate row.

```
Name        | Type 
------------|-------
mark_id     | int
student_id  | int
semester_id | int
paper_grade | int
```

Don't be concerned about the ids being repeated for every row - as long as there are no dependencies in between them, you're fine.

I'd also suggest changing `decimal(11,0)` to `int`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I used the sessionYear as a student may be now in 4th Semester. So, when I try to select all marks of 2nd Semester students, all the 2nd semester marks of students currently now in 4th semester will also appear. So, during the report generation, I would select only the marks in the current session year. As for using decimal, at one point of time, marks were given as 20.5 for the paper with 25 marks total. Then my system would roundup the number when generating the final report.

Comment: You forgot paper

Comment: @fdiengdoh I think you should move the column `year` to the table with semesters.